# Import vcf in iOS Simulator: "Unable to open contact card"

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, contacts, vcf-vcard

I used to import some contacts in the iOS Simulator by drag-and-dropping vcf cards in the phone, but now, whatever version of vcf I'm using (3.0, 2.1), whatever version of iOS (10.3, 13.2), I got the same error message all the times: `Unable to open contact card`

Anybody has the same problem or it's only me ?

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem. Did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the Simulators may have stopped supporting this import method. Although I can't find any official documentation on this.

I would suggest creating a small app in Xcode that accesses and writes to the contacts book on the simulator. This worked for me (I used the repo as a starting point - https://github.com/adhoclabs/ios-sample-contacts-import)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, can't get the drag and drop to work anymore - kinda annoying.

I ended up creating a small SwiftUI application where you can input how many contacts you want the app to create.
The numbers and names are just random characters and numbers - but they create valid contacts, where you can test performance in your app.

Here you have the complete code - remember to add access to Contacts to the plist:

```
import SwiftUI
import Contacts

struct ContentView: View {
@State var howManyContacts: String = ""
@State var isError: Bool = false
@State var isWorking: Bool = false
@State var isShowingDone: Bool = false

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        VStack {
            TextField("Number of contacts to create", text: $howManyContacts)
                .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                .border(.black)
                .padding()
            
            if isError {
                Text("You can only use int.")
                    .tint(.red)
            }
            
            if isShowingDone {
                Text("You created \(howManyContacts) contacts to the phonebook.")
            }

            Button {
                isWorking = true
                isError = false
                if let passedInteger = NumberFormatter().number(from: howManyContacts) {
                    Task {
                        //await createContacts(passedInteger.intValue)
                    }
                } else {
                    isError = true
                    isWorking = false
                }
            }label: {
                Text("Create contacts")
            }
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            .disabled(isWorking)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

func randomString(_ length: Int) -> String {
    
    let letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
    return String((0..<length).map{ _ in letters.randomElement()! })
}

func randomNumber(_ length: Int) -> String {
    let letters = "0123456789"
    return String((0..<length).map{ _ in letters.randomElement()! })
}

func createContacts(_ howManyToCreate: Int) async {

    for _ in 1...howManyToCreate {
        var contactToCreate: CNMutableContact = CNMutableContact()
        
        contactToCreate.givenName = randomString(5)
        contactToCreate.familyName = randomString(5)
        
        contactToCreate.phoneNumbers.append(CNLabeledValue(label: CNLabelPhoneNumberiPhone, value: CNPhoneNumber(stringValue: randomNumber(8)) ))
        let store = CNContactStore()
        let saveRequest = CNSaveRequest()
        
        saveRequest.add(contactToCreate, toContainerWithIdentifier:nil)
        try! store.execute(saveRequest)
    }
    
    isWorking = false
}
}
```

If you want to clone the project, you can find the repo here: https://github.com/AndersSoftware/Fake-iOS-contacts